# Assigns at least one unique item to each users at random without repetition

Tags: javascript

Assign at least one unique item to each users at random. e.g if 5 items & 5 users, each users get 1 items. if 4 items & 5 users, only 4 users get 1 items each. if 7 items & 4 users, then 3 users get 2 items each & 1 user get 1 item and so on. The script below was meant to achieved this but got a wrong result.

```
  assignItemsToUsers() {

let items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "item1",
    tag: 1900
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "item2",
    tag: 1876
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "item3",
    tag: 1575
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "item4",
    tag: 4783
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "item5",
    tag: 67894
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "item6",
    tag: 66789
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "item7",
    tag: 67890
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "item8",
    tag: 87654
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "item9",
    tag: 94948
  }
];


let users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "user1",
    userID: 38494
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "user2",
    userID: 84844
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "user3",
    userID: 47483
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "user4",
    userID: 83735
  }
];


let results = [];
            let tempResults = [];

            for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

                const item = items[i];

                const randomUser = users[Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length)];//pick user at random

                randomUser.tempitem = item;//asign item to this user
                tempResults.push(randomUser);//push to tempResults

            }

            //Group assigned items to their respective user
            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                const user = users[i];

                let myluckyitems = [];
                for (let index = 0; index < tempResults.length; index++) {
                    //check where tempResults[index].id == user.id
                    const assigneduser = tempResults[index];

                    if (user.id == assigneduser.id) {
                        //True: this was the assigned user.
                        myluckyitems.push(assigneduser.tempitem);
                    }

                }

                //all items assigned, then append to user object & push to results
                if (myluckyitems.length > 0) {
                    user.items = myluckyitems;
                    results.push(user);
                }

            }
            console.log(results);
}
```

**Actual Result**

```
 results = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: user1,
                    userID: 38494,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: item1,
                            tag: 1900
                        },
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: item1,
                            tag: 1900
                        }
                    ],

                    tempitem: {
                        id: 1,
                        name: item1,
                        tag: 1900
                    },

                },

                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: user2,
                    userID: 84844,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: item2,
                            tag: 1876
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: item2,
                            tag: 1876
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: item2,
                            tag: 1876
                        },
                    ],

                    tempitem: {
                        id: 2,
                        name: item2,
                        tag: 1876
                    },
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: user3,
                    userID: 47483,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: item3,
                            tag: 1575
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: item3,
                            tag: 1575
                        }
                    ],

                    tempitem: {
                        id: 3,
                        name: item3,
                        tag: 1575
                    },
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: user4,
                    userID: 83735,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: item4,
                            tag: 4783
                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: item4,
                            tag: 4783
                        }
                    ],

                    tempitem: {
                        id: 4,
                        name: item4,
                        tag: 4783
                    },
                }
            ];
```

**Expected Results**

```
results = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: user1,
                    userID: 38494,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: item1,
                            tag: 1900
                        },
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            name: item5,
                            tag: 67894
                        },
                        {
                            id: 9,
                            name: item9,
                            tag: 94948
                        }
                    ],
                },

                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: user2,
                    userID: 84844,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: item2,
                            tag: 1876
                        },
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            name: item6,
                            tag: 66789
                        },


                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: user3,
                    userID: 47483,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            name: item3,
                            tag: 1575
                        },
                        {
                            id: 7,
                            name: item7,
                            tag: 67890
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: user4,
                    userID: 83735,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            name: item4,
                            tag: 4783
                        },
                        {
                            id: 8,
                            name: item8,
                            tag: 87654
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ];
```

The difference is that, the actual results returns repeated items for each users and not all items were assigned to users, it also appends the `tempitem` property to each user which is not needed.

The expected results, assigns unique items to each users without repetition and also ensure that an item must be assigned to a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
  return array;
}

function assign() {
  const itemsLength = items.length;
  for (var i=itemsLength+1, shuffledArray=[]; i--;) shuffledArray.push(i);
  shuffledArray = shuffleArray(shuffledArray);
  
  const eachUserItems = itemsLength/users.length;
  
  Object.entries(users).map(([key, value]) => {
      for(i = 0; i < Math.round(eachUserItems); i++) {
        users[key]['items'] = users[key]['items'] || [];
        var popNewIndex = shuffledArray.pop();
        var objectToInsert = items.find((i) => i.id == popNewIndex + 1);
        users[key]['items'].push(objectToInsert);
      }
  });  
  
  return users;
}
```

This would give you expected items always assigned randomly to users

ps.

Also simple idea here is that rather than randomising on every loop we would make a random list of values that we would pop one by one. We can use randomise value to fetch value out of list by id and assign it. As list is supposed to have unique values which are randomised it would make sure no value is assigned again to any other user.

Comment: I noticed the users array is being altered direct such that if the function is run the second time, the previous items will be appended to the new items. Is there a way i can make a copy of the original users array so i don't alter it directly.

I tried this ```let newUsers = users;```

``` newUsers[key]['items'] = newUsers[key]['items'] || [];```

but didn't solve the problem.

Comment: while copying data of json from `users` to `newUsers` you would want to do this `let newUsers = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(users));`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that (excuse me for possible  mistakes, I didnt test it)

```
const users = [...] 
const items = [...]
const results = []

const random_func = () => {
   let available_users = [...users]
   items.forEach(item => {
        
       // if available users are zero, re-populate the array (it means that everyone has a item
        if(available_users.length === 0) available_users = [...users]
       //get a random user from available users array
       const random_user_index = Math.floor(Math.random() * available_users.length)
       const temp_user = available_users(random_user_index)

       //remove user from available users
       available_users.splice(i, 1);
       
       //check if user already exists into results array
       if(results.length > 0) {
          objIndex = results.findIndex((obj => obj.id == temp_user.id));
          if(objIndex === -1) results.push({...temp_user, items: [{...item}]}
          else results[index].items.push(item)
        }else {
           results.push({...temp_user, items: [{...item}]}
        }
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code. It's tested and produces the expected result.

```
const minItems = Math.round(items.length / users.length);
const assignedItems = [];

const usersWithItems = users.map((user) => {
   user.items = new Array(minItems).fill(0).map(() => {
      let isNew = false;
      let item;
      do {
          item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
          if(!assignedItems.includes(item.id))
            isNew = true;
      } while(isNew == false);
      if(item){
          assignedItems.push(item.id);
          return item;
      }
   });
   return user; 
})

const balanceItems = items.filter(item => !assignedItems.includes(item.id));
balanceItems.forEach((item) => {
  const randomUserNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * users.length);
  usersWithItems[randomUserNo].items.push(item);
})

console.log(usersWithItems);
```

Comment: This freezes my web browser. i am using plain javaScript. No typescript included.

Answer (score 0):

Lets's try to simplify your task, lets imagine you have unknown number of elements

`const items = [1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2];`

and unknown number of users

`const users = [{ name: "Tom", items: []}, { name: "John", items: [] }, name: "Steve", items: [] }];`

and you have to assign those items to user so your code would be

```
const items = [1, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2];
const users = [{ name: "Tom", items: []}, { name: "John", items: [] }, { name: "Steve", items: [] }];
let currentUserIndex = 0;

while (items.length) {
   const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    
   users[currentUserIndex].items.push(items[randomIndex]);
   
   items.splice(randomIndex, 1);
   
   if (currentUserIndex === users.length - 1) {
    currentUserIndex = 0;
   } else {
    currentUserIndex++; 
   }
}
```